# How to display data related by foreign key

Tags: angular

Suppose there is such a structure of the application. [image]
How in the interface to display the name from the table "fields" for the table "report". I tried to do something like this but nothing works.

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports">
  <div [(ngModel)]='report.platforms_id'>
    <div *ngFor="let paltform  of paltforms">
      <div [(ngModel)]='paltform.fields_id'>
        <div *ngFor="let field  of fields">
          {{field.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports">
  <div *ngFor="let platform  of platforms">
    <div *ngIf="report.platform_id==platform.platform_id">
      <div *ngFor="let field  of fields">
        <div *ngIf="field.name==platform.name">
          {{field.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given ID of an object which allows you to retrieve it from a collection.
So unless you have exact reference to another object you wont be able to access its properties.

Here is one of a potential way of accessing properties the field properties.
For the sake of example I will create collections of fields, platforms and reports where each IDs will correspond to index in array.

```
reportsArray = [{report_id: 0, platform_id: 1},{report_id: 1, platform_id: 1}];
platformArray = [{platform_id: 0, name: 'A', field_id: 0}];
fieldsArray = [{field_id: 0, name: 'A'}];
```

So to make it work in your example you should do it in following fashion:

```
 <div *ngFor="let report of reportsArray"> 
   <div>{{platformArray[report.platform_id].name}}</div>
   <div>{{fieldsArray[platformArray[report.platform_id].field_id].name}}</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You necesary must have a json data, I must supouse is

```
[
{report_id:1,platforms_id:2,platforms:[
      platforms_id:2,name="two",fields_id:4,fields:[
           {field_id:4,name="four"},
           {field_id:4,name="four-four"}
          ]
      ],
      platforms_id:2,name="two-two",fields_id:3,fields:[
           {field_id:3,name="three"},
           {field_id:3,name="three-three"}
          ]
      ]
,
...
]
```

then you can do

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports">
  <!--see the inner for use report.platforms -->
  <div *ngFor="let platform of report.platforms">
      <!--see the inner for use platform.fields -->
      <div *ngFor="let field of platform.fields">
          {{field.name}}
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```